# How can I change iFrame from px to %

Tags: html, css, iframe

So I have looked through the site and have noticed that people have been having the same trouble as me.  When I created my website, I did it based off of my screen's dimensions.  When I used other computers, I noticed that because the iFrame is in px ad not percentages, that it doesn't look as nice.

I was told to fix this, all I needed to do was to put within my CSS: height = 100%;.
However, no matter what I do, it is not working.  I have tried to make the body within the CSS to have the height as 100% and even tried it within the HTML document itself.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  Here is the code:

```
html { 
  background: url(http://images.wikia.com/zelda/images    /f/ff/Hyrule_Castle_in_Twilight.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  }

  body{
      text-align:center;
      height: 100%;
  }

  a{
    color:black;
      text-decoration: none;
  }

  b{      
    border:3px solid;
    padding:0.2em 0.6em;
    background:#FFFF99;
    border-radius:25px;
    width:auto;
    }

  b:hover {background-color:gray;}

iframe{
    border:8px solid; 
    background-color:#FFFF99;
    }
```

and for my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Twilight Princess: About</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ztp.css"/>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="content">
        <iframe src="about_info.html" name="content" width="70%" height="70%"></iframe>        
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
        <p>
        <b><a href="about.html">About</a></b>
        <b><a href="script.html">Full Script</a></b> 
        <b><a href="characters.html">Characters</a></b>    
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/npVFj0O.gif" alt="yooooo"/> 
        <b><a href="graphs.html">Graphs</a></b>
        <b><a href="conclusion.html">Conclusion</a></b>
        <b><a href="download.html">Downloads</a></b>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
THE HTML INSIDE THE FRAME:
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Twilight Princess: About</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="about.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h2>About</h2>

                 <p>The Twilight Princess project is an investigatory look into the video game fantasy world of Hyrule. 
                This iteration of the Zelda series features a rich culture of humans and different fantasy creatures,
                all of which are being affected by a dramatic and evil takeover from a Shadow Realm.</p>

            <h2>Research Question</h2>


                <p>Our invetigation is particularly one of language used throughout the story of Twilight Princess. 
                Language is one of many parts of life that shows how different people are affected by the unfamiliar events in their lives. 
                We are looking to see what types of language different characters are using, and how that changes throughout the game. 
                What characters are helping our silent hero and how? By analyzing and carefully tracking the race, gender, 
                and linguistic patterns, we will be able to see.</p> 
            <p>
                This project has been completed by: Ashley Bakaitus, Eleanor Bennett, and Daniel Brabander.  With special thanks to David Birnbaum and Jon Chumra.
            </p>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

With its CSS:

```
html{
    font-family:"Times New Roman";
    font-size:20px;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are using an iframe instead of just having the content inside of the .content div? http://jsfiddle.net/E7csa/embedded/result/

Comment: because the other pages / links are going into that iframe.  from the menu at the bottom. (Sorry for the wait, I didn't see this post.)

Comment: The jsfiddle above is the closest I can do, just replace the <div> with the iframe. The problem with iframes is that search engines won't read it when it crawls the page, so it will only see the menu. It will also crawl the pages that are just the iframe, which won't have any navigation to the other pages. If the only reason to use an iframe is to have one page with the menu navigation, I would just copy the nav and have it in each page instead. Or if you want to dabble into php, you can include a universal navigation file that way, something like this: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/include.php

Comment: I know I am not really supposed to say this within comment space, but thanks.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Take away `div.content`, so only your `iframe` stays (you don't assign any CSS to `div.content`, so why is it there?).

Add `height: 100%` to the `head`.

Comment: so. I took out the div (it was there from a previous version) and added the height : 100% into the css.  But nothing changed.

Comment: Did you add `head { height: 100% }` to the stylesheet as well?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've defined a percentage to a child (the iframe), where it's 100% of it's parent (.content) which doesn't have any values assigned.

I took the height and width off of the iframe html

```
<iframe src="about_info.html" name="content"></iframe>
```

and added it to the CSS. The child is 100% of the width and height defined in the parent:

> ```
> iframe{
>   height:100%;
>   width:100%;
>   border:8px solid; 
>   background-color:#FFFF99;
> } 
> .content{
>   height:70%;
>   width:70%; 
>   }
> ```

Here's a jsfiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/d43Cw/

Comment: This helps with the iframe width, but for some reason it is, i don't know how else to put it, but stuck at 50px for height. no matter what I do, the iframe won't extend past that.

Comment: Can you post your current code somewhere, perhaps in a jsfiddle?

Comment: The problem is that you removed the .content div around the iframe. If you put it back in there like you originally had, it will fix it.

Comment: Actually, nothing happened. :(  I really don't know what is wrong.

Comment: I believe this is exactly what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/uXCgR/embedded/result/

Comment: I have tried that. Copied and pasted everything. however when I did refresh, it wasn't what I wanted.  Do you know of a way that I can show you the output that I mean?  **a way that will also allow for the content within the frame to be shown?  that is where I am having the issue.

Comment: Do you have this live up on a server somewhere? If you have it hosted, you can include that url, or you can edit the jsfiddle I last included to have the url of the iframe, for example : <iframe src="www.yourSite.com/about_info.html" name="content"></iframe> then fork that file and include it in your next response.

Comment: It is, but the version uploaded is the one I am trying to correct.  I would just change the one on the server but my partner knows how to do that and I don't.  Instead, I will just post above, within my question, the additional HTML code and its CSS.  Maybe you could just save it all and see what I mean. Hopefully that would work.